# Error after serving angular, Watchpack Error loop

Tags: angular

My angular app was working just fine, I imported some lib that I deleted after.
I start getting a loop of this line:
Watchpack Error (watcher): Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch

I remove node_module and re installed it, I close the vs code, I restarted my pc , nothing works.

Does anyone has an idea on why I get this error?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and my problem was that the project was running on a Network drive which in some way interfered with watchpack.
Try moving your project to local disk if you have it on network drive and check if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

please try to clean cache

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Comment: I already tried that :'(

Comment: I found out that is problem is related to the number of file watchers in visual studio, fixing it is easy in linux just run "set fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" but I didn't find a solution in windows Anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: i faced this (max_user_watches=524288) but with another message not like this message.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue in Vue. I thought it would be a node version issue but it's not. Must be system based issue. Tag me if you find the solution.

Comment: Well, I didn't find a solution but I found the cause, it's because I launched the tests, documentations, node and angular together and that takes so much watchers.